# Run junit test in parallel with surefire maven plugin

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

It is posible to configure surefire plugin to only run some test in parallel and others in sequence?

Also can surefire *forkCount* be used to run parallel tests declared into a jUnit Suite?

Comment: May I ask what you want to achieve, because a test must not depend on other tests. That means it doesn't matter in which sequence a test needs to run.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case some test needs exclusivity when they run. But the rest, the majority, can run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate maven profiles with two different surefire plugin configurations.

Comment: So I can create 2 JUnit Suites and on each profile i can specify what suite is should run?

Comment: Yes. You have a variety of inclusion/exclusion mechanisms supported by the surefire plugin to fine tune the selection of the runnable tests for each profile. For more details, check this out: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way to do this is as follows:

- Move sequential tests each into its own test suite in junit
- Move parallel tests all into the same suite.
- Set Parallel to "classes"

```html
configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>**/A01TestSuite.java</include>
      <include>**/A02ServiceTestSuite.java</include>
      <include>**/A03FlowTestSuite.java</include>
     </includes>
     <additionalClasspathElements>
      <additionalClasspathElement>${webinf.dir}</additionalClasspathElement>
     </additionalClasspathElements>
     <systemPropertyVariables>
      <log4j.configuration>file:${l4j.test}/log4j.test.properties</log4j.configuration>
     </systemPropertyVariables>
     <forkMode>always</forkMode>
     <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx512m</argLine>
     <parallel>classes</parallel>
     <threadCount>10</threadCount>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the configuration of the maven-surefire-plugin in the pom.xml file.

```
<configuration>
    <parallel>all</parallel>
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    <threadCountSuites>2</threadCountSuites>
    <threadCountClasses>2</threadCountClasses>
    <threadCountMethods>6</threadCountMethods>
    <parallelTestTimeoutInSeconds>3.5</parallelTestTimeoutInSeconds>
    <parallelTestTimeoutForcedInSeconds>5</parallelTestTimeoutForcedInSeconds>
    <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
    <includes>
        <include>**/FunctionTestSuite.java</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

A detailed explanation can be found at this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-junit-parallel-tests). It gives a complete description step by step to run JUnit tests parallel with surefire-maven-plugin.

**Note:** This code snippet shows all the available options. You can change or remove some options as per your need!

Comment: I am the developer of Surefire, so I can answer your questions.
If you don't like reading our documentation, you can turn to more easy style and use IntelliJ IDEA. It is a great tool using the autocompletion. This feature helps you to add new config parameters and the documentation appears while you hower the mouse over the lines.

Comment: `<include>FunctionTestSuite.class</include>` is wrong.
It should be `<include>**/FunctionTestSuite.java</include>` or `<include>FunctionTestSuite</include>`.

Comment: Personally i would not set `parallelTestTimeoutForcedInSeconds` unless it is a performance testset. The timeout should be 10 times of expected exec time.

Comment: Do not stick only to the [Spring friendly tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com). Lets read the original [tutorials](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).

Comment: I have added all the possible options and written in note to use just as per needs.